# multiply matrices on python 3

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

anyone know why I got the wrong result? I know the there is a mistake in the last line in the code which is f=p0*pn*p

```
import numpy as np

def passage(n,i,j):
    # this function calculate the first time passage distribution after n 
    #steps starting at i and end at j.

    p=np.matrix([[0,1,0,0],[0.5,0,0.5,0],[0,.5,0,.5],[0,0,1,0]])

    p0=p[:]
    for k in range(len(p)): # let elements in column j be zeros
        p0[k,j]=0

    p1=p0[:]
    for k in range(len(p)): #let element in column j and row j be zeros 
        p1[j,k]=0

    pn=np.linalg.matrix_power(p1,n-2)


    f=p0*pn*p      # this line gives us wrong result. why


    return f
```

Comment: `*` is **not** a matrix product, but the elementwise product.

Comment: What is the right or wrong results?  This question is woefully incomplete.  It needs a MVC example, and explanation of what  you want.

Comment: I compared the result from the code with analytic result and Mathematica calculation.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem not on the `np.matrix` class, which all of `p`, `p0`, and `pn` are instances of when multiplication to get `f`.

Comment: for i=j=0 and n=4 , the expected output is f= [[0.125, 0, 0.357, 0], [0, 0.1875, 0, 0.1875],[0.1875, 0, 0.5625, 0],[0, 0.375, 0, 0.375]]  @h

Comment: @hpaulj  for i=j=0 and n=4 , the expected output is f= [[0.125, 0, 0.357, 0], [0, 0.1875, 0, 0.1875],[0.1875, 0, 0.5625, 0],[0, 0.375, 0, 0.375]]

Answer (score 1):

One potential source of problems:

```
p0=p[:]
```

produce a `view`, not a `copy`.  That means that after those 2 loops (which probably can be written without looping), `p`, `p0` and `p1` have the same values.

Did you actually test this code line by line, making sure each step was correct?  When I write functions in Python, and especially `numpy` have test out all steps interactively.

Another thing - unless you really need it, don't use `np.matrix`.  Stick with `np.array` when creating arrays, even 2d ones.  And use `np.dot` (or `@`) if you need matrix multiplication.

A quick rewrite of your function:

```
def passage(n,i,j):
    p=np.array([[0,1,0,0],[0.5,0,0.5,0],[0,.5,0,.5],[0,0,1,0]])
    p0=p.copy()
    p0[:,j] = 0
    p1=p0.copy()
    p1[j,:] = 0
    pn=np.linalg.matrix_power(p1,n-2)
    f = p0@pn@p    # or p0.dot(pn.dot(p))
    return f

In [15]: passage(4,0,0)
Out[15]: 
array([[ 0.125 ,  0.    ,  0.375 ,  0.    ],
       [ 0.    ,  0.1875,  0.    ,  0.1875],
       [ 0.1875,  0.    ,  0.5625,  0.    ],
       [ 0.    ,  0.375 ,  0.    ,  0.375 ]])
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use [np.copy()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.copy.html) to copy your `p` matrix.

```
p0 = np.copy(p)
p1 = np.copy(p0)
```

If you still don't get the expected answer, then you might want to have a look at [np.dot()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) and [np.matmul()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html).

Also note that [PEP465](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#whatsnew-pep-465) introduced `@` as a matrix multiplication operator.